# How to control specific map and legend colors in mapview package?

Tags: r, spatial, r-mapview

I want to use mapview to visualize the below spatial dataframe (sf object), with specific colors on both the map and legend. Assigning the `zcol` parameter to 'Commodity' will display all values, but when I specify a custom set of color values using the `col.regions` parameter, it shuffles the order I specify (i.e. where Alumina & Antimony are labeled pink and Cobalt is blue). How can I change my mapview call so that I have these one-to-one mappings with my data values and color choices?

```
library(mapview); library(tibble)
reprexdf <- structure(list(Commodity = c("Alumina", "Antimony", "Bauxite", 
"Chromite", "Coal", "Cobalt", "Copper", "Diamonds", "Gold", "Graphite", 
"Ilmenite", "Iron Ore", "Lanthanides", "Lead", "Lithium", "Manganese", 
"Molybdenum", "Nickel", "Palladium", "Phosphate", "Platinum", 
"Potash", "Rutile", "Scandium", "Silver", "Tantalum", "Tin", 
"Titanium", "Tungsten", "U3O8", "Vanadium", "Zinc"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(74.1867018689986, 43.1980200148667), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(71.7552595131403, 39.6561200773791
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(68.4892405701349, 
    52.7147846055392), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(32.0340206057459, 
    38.6167768843658), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(17.7734702058381, 
    51.5204514008904), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(22.2954101440738, 
    51.2054063543333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(59.3802911872375, 
    46.5120764901861), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(30.9448779697714, 
    62.7866761615543), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(19.6991862079032, 
    68.0630555165806), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(23.3633810296335, 
    61.2323113198727), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(22.6936032890073, 
    64.400202153036), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(16.2933393846649, 
    41.115478005968), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(74.8921184988305, 
    53.4147177051134), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-4.62308734592504, 
    38.4973852079805), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-5.55711136406121, 
    38.7609039997681), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(46.1696365421761, 
    37.8054777412675), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(69.1338599506306, 
    45.1046447967609), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(26.0266877752458, 
    61.6213181277374), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(14.678433940652, 
    65.8316734439636), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(64.8626780282562, 
    36.2120365056795), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(75.2744534960289, 
    41.7416342085414), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(7.54172575797454, 
    54.7804503893017), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.35439579518009, 
    62.2667697053924), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(25.9135045170651, 
    58.1849810922895), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(8.50142345297422, 
    58.1222871519439), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(24.8503658161678, 
    60.0844617435652), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-8.16011736668124, 
    38.1627405413439), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(58.4011176975426, 
    37.8798048427329), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-9.25666269137908, 
    41.900952474145), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(63.3159694601457, 
    39.6821149461387), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(25.5040625781002, 
    66.628066442373), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-6.02123775666737, 
    54.8933062105439), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -9.25666269137908, 
ymin = 36.2120365056795, xmax = 75.2744534960289, ymax = 68.0630555165806
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), groups = structure(list(Commodity = c("Alumina", "Antimony", 
"Bauxite", "Chromite", "Coal", "Cobalt", "Copper", "Diamonds", 
"Gold", "Graphite", "Ilmenite", "Iron Ore", "Lanthanides", "Lead", 
"Lithium", "Manganese", "Molybdenum", "Nickel", "Palladium", 
"Phosphate", "Platinum", "Potash", "Rutile", "Scandium", "Silver", 
"Tantalum", "Tin", "Titanium", "Tungsten", "U3O8", "Vanadium", 
"Zinc"), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Commodity = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

mapview(reprexdf, zcol = 'Commodity',
        col.regions = c("pink", "pink", "#6FB000", "grey90", "black", "blue", "#F8766D", "#00ADFA", "lightgoldenrod4", "grey", "grey90", "grey30", "grey90", "#00C19F", "grey90", "grey90", "grey90", "#00BFC4", "darkslategrey", "#619CFF", "darkslategrey", "grey90", "pink", "pink", "grey80", "pink", "#FF61C3", "pink", "grey90", "green", "pink", "#FF699C"
```

))

[image: out of order color labels]

Comment: This is a bug with legend creation in mapview. Can you please file an issue at https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues. Additionally, please note that you are assigning 35 colors to 32 point features, which is also likely to mess things up.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Wasn't sure it was a bug so made sure to ask here first. I'll do that now. And thanks for the note I'll edit the above post to make it 32 to 32